# Create dynamic variables from file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I have a geoJSON file containing markers' ID and the Lat and Long of each one. (see JSON below).

I'm using `$getJSON` to access its properties.

The geoJSON file changes constantly (adding or remove markers). So, what I want to do is to loop through each marker and create a the number of variables my file has, and then I'll set Click event listeners to each variable.

I'd like something as follows:

```
$.getJSON("MyFile.geojson", 
    function(JSON_Result) {
    var JSON_Features_Count = JSON_Result['features'].length;
    for (i=0; i<JSON_Features_Count; i++){
        var coordinates = JSON_Result['features'][i]['geometry']['coordinates']; //Lat = coordinates[1]; Long = coordinates[0]
        var Marker_i = // this variable should be dynamic, because I don't know the number of markers my file has. 
                new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1],coordinates[0]),
                map: map,
            });
    }
});
```

Here is a example of my JSON file:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 1}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -43.256001299999895, -18.966999944999898] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 2}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -43.3659564559999, -18.733241581 ] } },
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do this way..

```
var alldataarr = [];//global variable to store all markers

//loop to deal with jSON
for (var i = 0; i < obj.DATA.length; i++) {
var arrobj = new Object;
arrobj.id = obj.DATA[i].id;
arrobj.district = obj.DATA[i].district;
arrobj.contenttitle = obj.DATA[i].contenttitle;
arrobj.x = obj.DATA[i].x;
arrobj.y = obj.DATA[i].y;
alldataarr.push(arrobj);
GMapCreateMarker(i, obj.DATA[i].x, obj.DATA[i].y, obj.DATA[i].contenttitle, 'camera-web.png')
);
```

every time  you renew the json file,just modify the content of alldataarr and redraw the marker.